# Loop through xlsm files, getting error 438

Tags: vba

I took some code from here and I can not manipulate it.
Wanna iterate through few xlsm files in one directory. So that each row from single xlsm file will be shown in  a Summary Workbook.

unfortunately , i get error 438, probably beacuse of the Dim methode.

Please  help me figure it out :)

```html
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()

Dim SummarySheet As Workbook
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


' open summary workbook .
Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\Projects\SuperProject\BorotNisayon\"

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 2

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsm")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""

    ' Open a source workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

    ' Set the source range to be A2 through P2.
    ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
    ' It can span multiple rows.
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Sheets("Drill").Range("A2:P2")

    ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
    ' be the same size as the source range.
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("A2:P2" & NRow)
   

    ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Copy

    ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = Dir()
Loop



   
 End Sub
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: on the Dims probably

Comment: I doubt that. When the error message pops up, click on `Debug` and tell us what line the code breaks on

Comment: Also the code only open one source xlsm file and than the error emerges

Comment: Try to replace `DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Copy` with `DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value`

Comment: Not working. There  is another way to debug it ? beacuse the target VBA is immediately close

Comment: Step through the code using `F8` and see where the code breaks

Comment: `SummarySheet.Range("A2:P2" & NRow)` is probably wrong.

Comment: I agree with @VincentG. You're missing a reference to a worksheet. Your `SummarySheet` variable is named poorly, as it refers to a workbook and not a sheet

Comment: @TimStack in fact I totally missed the workbook named "sheet", I just saw the row number problem in the range!

Comment: @VincentG And I missed the row number issue! We complete each other :) I must add that the row number isn't code breaking. If NRow contains e.g. the integer `10`, then the range would be `A2:P210`

Comment: Niether of those dont work for me

Comment: Alternativly I try to use this code....but I have got issues with it too

Comment: Sub LoopThroughDirectory()


Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
MyFile = Dir("C:\Projects\SuperProject\BorotNisayon\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

  If MyFile = "ProjectSummary.xlsm" Then
  Exit Sub
  End If

Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
Range("A2:P2").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Summary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 16))

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub